# Replacing SOD with fetch (handling JS library dependencies - *in the future*)

Tags: javascript, rest

Anticipating a future, I am experimenting with *User Custom Actions* in the new Document Library View Microsoft has so kindly provided to the First Release Office365 tenants.

Since there is almost nothing SharePoint left (no JSOM, no SOD) I am trying new technologies to get JS library dependencies working.
*Note that Microsoft does load RequireJS, but if they can get rid of the SP Object, JSOM etc.

I am not going to rely on anything but a modern Browser*

`fetch` is Chrome and Firefox only for now (april 2016) http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

```
fetch('https://.../file.js')
    .then(function (q) {
        return q.text();
    })
    .then(eval) //for those who think evil! It does the same as the (old) DOM abusing below
    .then(function(){
        //do stuff
    });
```

Since this is all Promises, this would make loading **multiple libraries** a breeze

Any cons in using this over:
(*good old abusing the DOM for no reason other then get a file loaded/executed*):

```
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "https://.../file.js";
element.load = function(){
    //do stuff
}
document.head.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `fetch` be restricted by Same Origin Policy? And thinking about future, isn't eval (by default) disallowed in Content Security Policy?

Comment: Thats up to Microsoft. I have no idea how difficult it would be for them to implement.. but SharePoint is a 15 year old beast, I can image it would take some serious regression testing. In that aspect getting rid of all the (old) SharePoint shit in the new Document Library makes sense to me now. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

Comment: Judging by the handfull of times ``eval`` is used in the new Library View [CoreMinShellG2BundleA](https://prod.msocdn.com/16.00.1226.008/en-US/JSC/CoreMinShellG2BundleA.js) library; Microsoft has no intention yet to go CSP